# How can I disable keybindings / keybind in GNU screen?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnu-screen, iterm

I use `iTerm2` on Mac and have customized <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to send hex `0x01` and `0x05` when pressed - which makes the cursor jump to the start and end of the line when typing or editing commands (opposed to one word at a time) - and the <kbd>alt</kbd> key plus an arrow makes the cursor move one word at a time.

This works fine on remote linux systems when using SSH, until I start a screen session. The <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> still works fine, but when I try to use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> I just get a message in the `screen` status area:

```
No other window.
```

I found documentation that suggested adding these lines to `/etc/screenrc` or `~/.screenrc`  would bind the keys to next and previous windows:

```
bindkey "^[[5D" prev
bindkey "^[[5C" next
```

And I thought the syntax for unbinding was to use this line with no command:

```
bindkey "^[[5D"
bindkey "^[[5C"
```

I've also tried it with as follows:

```
bindkey "^[[01"
bindkey "^[[05"
```

None of these things seem to work.

`/etc/screenrc` is completely unchanged for `Ubuntu 16.04` and there is no `~/.screenrc` file at the moment ( i.e. nothing non-standard interfering )

How can I unbind this or debug it further to figure out where the hangup is?

Comment: Do you have to use `screen`? Does this issue happen in `tmux` (an alternative)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `0x01` is Control-A which is the default command character in screen, so when you do <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> twice you have the default action binding of *other*, i.e. other window, hence the message.

You can change to a different command character, eg Control-b when you start screen:

```
screen -e^Bb
```

or you can put in your `~/.screenrc` the line

```
escape ^Bb
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to send the character ^A (Ctrl+A). This is the same character that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> sends, and ^A is the default prefix character for Screen's key bindings.

`bindkey "^[[5D" prev` in the Screen configuration is useless for two reasons. First, this defines what happens when Screen receives this escape sequence *after the prefix character*, i.e. after a ^A. Second, `^[[5D` is what some terminals send for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, but you've reconfigured your terminal to send something different (^A).

Instead of making <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> send ^A, make it send `^[[1~` or `^[OH` (where `^[` is an escape character). Likewise make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> send `^[4~` or `^[OF` instead of ^E. These are escape sequences normally sent by the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys.